# Link to add ics to Google Calendar stopped working

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a link on a website to let users add an ICS feed to their google Calendar. Using this code:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=https://<etc>
```

It worked for 3-4 years but not anymore. The message Google sends me is:

```
This email address isn't associated with an active Google Calendar account: https://<etc>
```

If I enter the ics feed manually things work ok: the feed is parsed as should. No errors.

Any idea where to look to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I too have this problem. Did you solve it?

My tests show that it works when using URLs with **http**, like:

```
www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=http%3A%2%2Fwww.example.com%2FCalendar%2FPublic%2520Events.ics
```

But **not** with **https**, like:

```
www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=https%3A%2%2Fwww.example.com%2FCalendar%2FPublic%2520Events.ics
```

My workaround for this is to use http in the link, but redirect it to https in the web server. Not very elegant, but it works. The GET won't be encrypted, but at least the answer is.

**EDIT**: Actually, it can be a huge security risk sending the GET over http instead of https if you don't do any more authentication than via query string parameters, which can be hard for calendar feeds. Anyone who can sniff the GET can send the same request over https themselves.

Comment: Thanks for updating; indeed it works via http instead of https. But not very safe, unfortunately.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this URL format still works? If I click this: http://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=http://www.goduke.com/export/icalendar.dbml?db_oem_id=4200&sport_id=1845&season=2014 -- then it says "You don't have access", but if instead I manually use Google Calendar's "Add by URL" feature with: http://www.goduke.com/export/icalendar.dbml?db_oem_id=4200&sport_id=1845&season=2014 -- then it works fine. Leads me to believe there's an issue with the "automatic" subscribe URL format, right?

Comment: I can confirm it's broken for me also

Comment: Unfortunately, my wordpress instance is rewriting http to https :(.

Comment: just confirmed that https on google's side works but have to use http on my own.  in my case, this isn't ok so I have to tell them how to "add by URL" on google calendar's site

Comment: `%3A%2F%2F` instead of `%3A%2%2F`.

Comment: Using webcal:// instead of http:// or https:// worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Use `webcal` protocol for the calendar address:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=webcal%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FCalendar%2FPublic%20Events.ics
```

Comment: This is the only answer here that worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Has anyone noticed what happens if you click a link like this on a mobile device with google calendar app installed? I just get a sync error, but without the app it loads into a browser and syncs fine

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so for me, none of the other answers on this page worked. But I figured it out with bits and pieces of others:

Link to my calendar's ics:

```
https://example.com/calendar?id=a304036ea5a474ee5d80a100d79c231c
```

The right way to link it to Google Calendar:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cid=webcal%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcalendar%3Fid%3Da304036ea5a474ee5d80a100d79c231c
```

The key here is adding it using the **webcal** protocol instead of the **https** protocol.

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Right now it works, even with `https`.

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FCalendar%2FPublic%20Events.ics
```

Comment: That saved me 30 seconds of my life :D

Answer (score 0):

They got more strict.
Now you have to use

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FCalendar%2FPublic%2520Events.ics
```

note the encoding.

Comment: Unfortunately, no bonus. Any links where I can find that Google changed this?

Comment: No I had to just hack at it till I got it to work. can I see one of your links that isn't working?

Comment: As early 2015 it looks like google has removed this functionality (or broken it for months). I've had to move to providing a url that the user has to copy into google.